# C - Returning a local pointer vs local variable

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, function-pointers

My question is regarding these two cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *foo1();
int *foo2();

int main()
{
   printf("so it's %d\n",*foo1());
   printf("so it's %d\n",*foo2());
}

int *foo1()
{
   int i1 = 5;
   return &i1;
}

int *foo2()
{
   int i2 = 5;
   int *p = NULL;
   p = &i2;
   return p;
}
```

**case1:**  When its the case with foo1(), we get an error because we are trying to return a copy of address to main whose data has been deleted(when we exit foo1() function)

**case2:** But in foo2() , it **doesn't give an error** though we are returning a copy to a pointer of local variable whose data will be deleted after we exit the foo2() function, **why is it so?**

TL;DR: why foo2() doesn't give an error but foo1() does?

TIA.

Comment: C or C++?  Also, g++, [gives a warning for both](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ee45849a93cd26d)

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the fact that *foo1* is returning an rvalue while *foo2* is returning an lvalue, which is a valid return even though the pointer address itself is invalid.

Comment: Why the double tag?

Comment: @NathanOliver In C ,since both somewhat have same concepts i tagged c++.

Comment: Your question is a clear indocator you have not really understood the concept of local variables and pointers. Please recap the chapters in your C book. If you learn C from online tutorials or youtube: **Don't!** They are incomplete at best.

Comment: @Olaf: Absolutely. Start with K & R, and do the example exercises.

Comment: @Bathsheba: K&R is outdated since 18 years now. C99 introduced a lot of  modern features and some incompatibilities to C90. A good book about modern C (C99, better C11) would be reasonable.

Comment: My doubt was that though it was undefined, it didn't give an error..so i wanted to clarify about it. Anyway thanks all for suggestions! :)

Comment: @valacmur98 "though it was undefined, it didn't give an error,so i wanted to clarify about it".  If C specified an error, that would be define behavior.  Undefined behavior means an error  is not required.  You _might_ get one, you might not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behaviour of both functions `foo1` and `foo2` are *undefined*, in both C and C++.

You are not allowed to *dereference* a pointer that points to a variable with automatic storage duration that's no longer in scope.

Tomorrow, `foo2()` may well give you an error too. Or the compiler might eat your cat.

Comment: Useful answer -- I'm always triple checking my code to ensure my cat won't be eaten by the compiler.

Comment: We should definitely want to avoid coding practices that cause compilers to eat cats! :O

Comment: I am sure the "compiler" can't eat your cat. The generated code when run can though.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Can you point to anywhere in the C standard to back up your claim? I think the compiler can eat both the program and the cat.

Comment: The compiler isn't performing Undefined Behavior by compiling the code that has Undefined Behavior. Compiling *any*  program is defined for the compiler.

Comment: The compiler might inject code into the program that invokes the compiler, at runtime, into cat-consumption mode.

Comment: @Bathsheba also, if the compiler wants to eat your cat for some input, it would have to mention that in it's manual. I will stay away from such a compiler.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: I would too. Which is why commercially savvy compiler vendors issue warnings.

Comment: @Bathsheba Exactly! The code when run, can eat your cat. The compiler can't! What I mean't is unless the UB actually happens, (when run) everything is safe.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, you are invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by returning a pointer to a local variable and dereferencing it.

Invoking undefined behavior does not mean you will always crash.  It means the behavior of the program is undefined.  It could crash, it could output strange results, or it could appear to work properly.  As you have seen, this behavior manifests itself in two of these ways in your program.

Making a seemingly unrelated change, such as adding an unused local variable or a `printf` for debugging, can change the way undefined behavior manifests itself.

Answer (score 1):

Both are undefined behavior, you cannot rely on the compiler giving you warnings for undefined behavior.

You are essentially doing the same thing in both functions and in fact both might result in the same assembly code to be generated.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of both case1 and case2 are undefined, you can't return pointer to local variable